# Remove second character only, in a string

Tags: php

I have a set of strings. Their values can be different from string to string. Here is an example of three strings:

```
$string1 = "505";
$string2 = "500";
$string3 = "601";
```

I need to remove the second 0 only yielding:

```
$string1 = "55";
$string2 = "50";
$string3 = "61";
```

I have tried `substr`, `str_replace` and `ltrim` but cannot produce my desired results.  Ideas?

Comment: You didn't try `substr_replace`?

Comment: @AbraCadaver, no...havent tried that one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Combine `substr` and `str_replace` and you get `substr_replace`:

```
$string1 = substr_replace($string1, '', 1, 1);
```

Comment: Perfect, works exactly how I need it to. I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use
`$string = substr($string,0,1).substr($string,-(strlen($string)-2));`